# Can list all keys using h5py but not with hdfstore

Tags: h5py, hdfstore

I would like to use pandas to read hdf5 files. But unfortunately I can not get it to work.
Using VS-code Jupiternotebook on Windows:

**This does not list anything and gives no error:**

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.HDFStore('D:/sample.h5' ) as f:
    print(list(f.keys()))
    pass
```

The output here is : nothing

**Same file but using h5py works fine:**

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('D:/sample.h5, 'r') as f:
   print(list(f.keys()))
   pass
```

The output here is :
['INDEX', 'NASTRAN']

I do not know in which way the file was created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Was this file created with `HDFStore`?  Review pandas docs for this.  I haven't used it, but I think it 'stores' dataframes, not numpy arrays (as `h5py`) does.

Comment: The `keys` docs suggests that you may need to use `HDFStore.keys('native')` or in some other way open the store in `native` mode to see the same sort of keys as `h5py`.

Comment: Might also try `f.info()`

Comment: this question would be clearer if you show `h5py` output.  Better yet if that distinguished between groups and datasets.   And if you compared a file written with h5py and one created with pytables.